# How to use plot [ If ] to show the points where $\sin x=0$? the code is given

Tags: plotting, conditional

I am using this code to get a result showing the points $x$ for which $\sin x=0$ as a thin stripe at $y=5$. But the plot I get is empty. I wonder if someone explains please what is wrong with this code? Maybe, Plot [If] is not defined for equality.

```
 Plot[  If[Sin[x] == 0, 5], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle ->  Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.015]], 
 PlotPoints -> 300]
```

Comment: You didn't provide an "else" clause to your `If[]`; what's `Plot[]` supposed to do for `x` that do not satisfy your equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NumberLinePlot`  and replace `Point`s with `Line`s:

```
nlp = NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] == 0, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Spacings -> 5, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.015]]] /. 
  Point[x_] :> Line[{x, {x[[1]], 0}}]
```

[image]

Show with plot of `Sin`:

```
Show[nlp, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> {-1, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to set these lines' height between say $4<y<5$?

Comment: @sara96, try replacing `Spacings -> 5` with `Spacings -> 4.5`

Answer (score 2):

One way like this.

```
fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Sin[x]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {White, PointSize[Large]}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.015]], 
   PlotPoints -> 300, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}];
fig2 = Plot[5, {x, 0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Sin[x]], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}, 
   PlotStyle -> None];
Show[fig1, fig2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can we have those red points as thin lines?